# Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies.The located

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, log4net

When we try to call a report from our application and download it in PDF format, we get the following error:

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

However, I passed the same solution from Visual Studio to a colleague who had not yet installed anything from SAP or log4net and it works without giving any errors. What could be the reason? The version of log4net we are using is 2.0.15 (we have already changed the parameters in the code specifying that the version was 2.0.15, but the error still remains).

It seems that the issue is related to the assembly reference of log4net. The error message indicates that the located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. This means that the version of the log4net assembly that is being loaded by the application does not match the version that the application is expecting.

It's possible that your colleague's machine has a different version of log4net installed, or a different version of a dependency that log4net relies on, which is why the application works on their machine but not on yours.

To resolve this issue, you may need to ensure that the correct version of log4net is installed on your machine and that all the necessary dependencies are also installed. You could also try cleaning and rebuilding the solution to ensure that all the references are up to date. Additionally, you may want to check that the assembly reference in your code is correctly pointing to the correct version of log4net.

we try to unistall all dll reistall it,reinstall a log4net 1.2.10 but the error was teh same
but when i shere the viusal studio solution to my collegue it works the obbjective is when i call a report page the applicatin create a crystal repor operative report and the convert it in to a pdf

Comment: That's strange. log4net 1.2.10.0 had a different PublicKeyToken (1b44e1d426115821). The one in your error message was used only starting from 1.2.11.0. This makes a binding redirect in your app.config the most probable culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If reinstalling the log4net DLL and cleaning/rebuilding the solution did not solve the issue, you may want to check if there are any conflicting dependencies that are causing the error. You can use a tool like Fusion Log Viewer to trace the loading of the log4net assembly and its dependencies. This can help you identify which dependency is causing the issue.

Another possible solution is to update your application's configuration file to redirect the log4net assembly to the correct version. You can add a bindingRedirect element to your configuration file to redirect the assembly reference to the correct version, like this:

```cs
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.15.0" newVersion="2.0.15.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This configuration will redirect any requests for the log4net assembly version 1.2.10 to version 2.0.15.